# Mysql query fast only first time run

Tags: mysql, performance, memory, join, flush

I have a mysql SELECT query which is fast (<0.1 sec) but only the first time I run it.  It joins 3 tables together (using indices) and has a relatively simple WHERE statement.  When I run it by hand in the phpmyadmin (always changing numbers in the WHERE so that it isn't cached) it is always fast but when I have php run several copies of it in a row, the first one is fast and the others hang for ~400 sec.  My only guess is that somehow mysql is running out of memory for the connection and then has to do expensive paging.

My general question is how can I fix this behavior, but my specific questions are without actually closing and restarting the connection how can I make these queries coming from php be seen as separate just like the queries coming from phpmyadmin, how can I tell mysql to flush any memory when the request is done, and does this sound like a memory issue to you?

Comment: you must do something wrong, without your actual SQL is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer at least in my case and I'm putting it here for anyone in the future who runs into a similar issue.  The query I was running had a lot of results returned and [MYSQL's query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) was causing a lot of overhead.  When you run a query MYSQL will save it and its output so that it can quickly answer future identical requests quickly.  All I had to do was put SQL_NO_CACHE and the speed was back to normal.  Just look out if your incoming query is large or the results are very large because it can take considerable resources for MYSQL to decide when to kick things out.